# Using df.apply to return the count of rows where a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an dataframe as given:

[image: Initial Dataframe]

Now as seen from the dataframe the player x lost 6 times and the player y lost 9 times. I want to make a dataframe which enlists the players and how many times they have lost. Hence the final dataframe should look like this

[image: Final Dataframe]

One option which I found was to use dataframe.apply wherein I could return the no of rows which maintained the condition. The code for the same is:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/sadik/Desktop/Data.csv')

df = df.apply(lambda x : True
            if x['Result'] == "Lost" else False, axis = 1)
num_rows = len(df[df == True].index)
print('Number of Rows in dataframe in which Condition is met: ',
      num_rows )
```

This gives me the ouput

```
runfile('C:/Users/sadik/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/sadik')
Number of Rows in dataframe in which Condition is met:  15
```

My question is how do I use the same logic to output the count by the name of the players as shown  in the expected ouput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the `Name` and then `agg`regate the total number of `Lost`s:

```
out = df.groupby("Name").Result.agg(lambda s: s.eq("Lost").sum()).to_frame("Count")
```

where we lastly turn it to a dataframe with the counts named `"Count"`,

to get

```
>>> out

      Count
Name
x         6
y         9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `groupby`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['x'] * 6 + ['y'] * 9, 'result': ['LOST'] * 15})


df.groupby('name').count()
>>>
    result
name    
x   6
y   9
```

In case you want to use `apply` you can do that too:

```py
df.groupby('name')[['result']].apply(lambda x: x.count())
```